# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't select

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have this code, but selection doesn't work.

```html
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="entity" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Students
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Teachers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" id="s" class="form-control" aria-label="..." oninput="f()">
```

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

Check this simplest Dropdown menu [Dropdown Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h)
I am not sure what exactly you are trying to get though.